# The wedge sum of two circles has fixed point property?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, algebraic-topology, fixed-point-theorems

The wedge sum of two circles has fixed point property?

I'm trying to find a continuous map from the wedge sum to itself, that this property fails, I couldn't find it, I need help.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If by circle you mean $S^1$, and the fixed point property is the claim that every continuous map into itself has a fixed point, for two circles like so: [image]

consider the map that rotates $A$ by 90 degrees, and sends all of $B$ to the image of $x$.

Comment: can you give more details please? thank you for your answer :)

Comment: if you rotate $A$ by 90 degrees, and send all of $B$ to the image of $x$, this is (i) a continuous map from the wedge of two circles to itself and (ii) sends no point to itself, i.e. has no fixed points

Comment: can I make a map, that rotate $90^o$ both circles as you do in the circle A? I think this map is well-defined and doesn't have fixed points.

Comment: Er it's not well defined: the point $x$ would be sent two different places.

Comment: yes, you're reason