# Does the figure eight ($S^1\vee S^1$) have the fixed point property?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, geometric-topology

Does the figure eight (The wedge sum of two circle $\simeq S^1\vee S^1$) has the fixed point property or not? How would you justify your answer?

Comment: 1. The figure "8" is the wedge sum of two circles. 2. Please edit your question to show your efforts on this problem, so that we might be able to help you more precisely.

Comment: I think this is what you've been looking for: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/243588/the-wedge-sum-of-two-circles-has-fixed-point-property

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot! :)

Comment: You're welcome. :)